# Backend for SharePoint 2019 Application

Tags: rest, sharepoint, graphql, asp.net-core-webapi, spfx

We are developing several SPFx based forms for SharePoint ONPrem 2019 application.

What is the ideal approach for its backend?

> Extend REST API for SharePoint
> OR
> Make .net Core 3.1 WebAPI and expose as custom service

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“It depends” is probably the right answer to this. Choosing a service you host within SharePoint Server has certain benefits but also multiple downsides. What is more appropriate or easier depends a lot on how much complexity you expect to have in your backend.

#### Hosting within SharePoint Server

This means you are exposing a web service e.g. using ISAPI over HTTP-based WCF services. This has the nice benefits that you are running *within* SharePoint so you have authentication built-in and you are able to work with the server-side SharePoint APIs (SSOM) directly.

On the downside, hosting your services like this also means that you are now deploying a SharePoint farm solution with all the problems this implies (e.g. deployment is more complicated, the development process is generally slowed down, any GAC problem you can think of). When you are within SharePoint, integrating external things also gets a bit more complicated.

#### Hosting externally

If you are hosting your web services externally, then you are free to choose any technology you want and are not limited by how SharePoint works on its own. This also makes development and deployment nicer since you can just choose any modern framework that takes care of this. And integration of external things also gets a lot easier.

On the downside, you will have to take care of authentication which may come with its own problems. And if you need to actually communicate with your SharePoint, then you are limited to client-side access, e.g. CSOM.

And speaking of CSOM, you have to keep in mind that there is no .NET Core support for CSOM for SharePoint on premises. Microsoft made it clear that there is no work going into that so you are effectively locked in to the .NET Framework if you want to use CSOM. That also means that you unfortunately cannot use a shiny ASP.NET Core 3.1 application since that only runs on .NET Core. If you wanted to use ASP.NET Core, you would have to stick to 2.1 (which is the last supported version that still runs on .NET Framework), or split up your architecture that the ASP.NET Core application doesn’t directly talk to the SharePoint but relays its work to some other (.NET Framework) service that then does the communication.

---

So in the end, it depends on what you want to do and with what problems you are able to live with.

Comment: thanks Mr. @poke. we feel the need to go hybrid, meaning some REST services on SP )(farm solution) where we need to fetch list data from SP. That REST service we will consume through our main web API service on .net Core 3.1 where our main code can live so we have all the technology stack like graphQL to take benefits of. That way we can use both SSOM and .net Core.

Answer (score 0):

With time, the best solution we found is to use .Net FX full version if you backend solely relies on SP lists and other dependencies.

Otherwise, if you backend uses SQL server, then better use the latest .net core. This is also since, some minor SP list operations you can do easily with JSOM directly from front end as well without need for CSOM.